# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, self

I'm trying to make a function to send a message to a specific user for this in my model I wrote this code

```
class SkypeBot(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.skype'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity', 'res.users']
    _description = 'My Skype'


    skype_login = fields.Char('Your skype Login')
    skype_password = fields.Char('Your skype password')
    skype_message = fields.Char(store=True)

    @api.multi
    def msg(self, message):

        partner_id = self.env['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)]).partner_id.id

        _logger.info('^^^^^' * 5)
        _logger.warning(partner_id)
        _logger.info('^^^^^' * 5)

        self.env['mail.message'].create({'message_type': 'notification',
                                         'subtype': self.env.ref('mail.mt_comment').id,  # subject type
                                         'body': message,
                                         'subject': 'Message subject',
                                         'partner_ids': [(4, partner_id), ],
                                         # partner to whom you send notification
                                         })
```

I want to call this method (msg) from another MySkype class:

```
class MySkype(skpy.SkypeEventLoop):
    def onEvent(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, skpy.SkypeNewMessageEvent):  

            message = ('New message from user {} at {}: \'{} \''.format(event.msg.userId,
                                                                   event.msg.time.strftime('%H:%M dd. %d.%m.%Y'),
                                                                   event.msg.content))


            _logger.info('--------'*5)
            _logger.warning(event)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(message)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            skype_model.SkypeBot.msg(message=message)

from skpy import Skype

sk = MySkype('+375', '1239qW', autoAck=True)
thread = threading.Thread(target=sk.loop)
thread.start()
```

but when this method is called I get an error

```
лют 10 10:42:00 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:00,618 8534 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
лют 10 10:42:50 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:50,620 8534 INFO odoo12 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2019 07:42:50] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 - 35 0.030 53.925
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:55,056 8534 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.skype_send_message: —--------------------------------------
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:55,056 8534 WARNING ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.skype_send_message: [SkypeNewMessageEvent]
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: Id: 1014
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: Type: NewMessage
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: Time: 2019-02-10 07:42:54
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: MsgId: 1549784574906
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:55,057 8534 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.skype_send_message: —--------------------------------------
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:55,057 8534 WARNING ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.skype_send_message: Test!Test!Test!Test!Test!
лют 10 10:42:55 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:42:55,057 8534 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.skype_send_message: —--------------------------------------
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: Exception in thread Thread-2:
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: Traceback (most recent call last):
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: self.run()
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: File "/opt/odoo12/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skpy/main.py", line 207, in loop
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: self.cycle()
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: File "/opt/odoo12/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skpy/main.py", line 196, in cycle
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: self.onEvent(event)
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: File "/opt/odoo12/odoo-custom-addons/skype_bot/skype_send_message.py", line 33, in onEvent
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: skype_model.SkypeBot.msg(message=message)
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: TypeError: msg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
лют 10 10:43:40 PK odoo12[8534]: 2019-02-10 07:43:40,702 8534 INFO odoo12 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2019 07:43:40] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 50.051
```

what am i doing wrong and how do i solve this problem

I tried using @ api.model it did not help me.
It seems I have a problem with the initialization of the odoo environment but I can understand exactly where

Comment: You're calling that function on the class itself rather than on an instance of the class, so you have to manually pass in an instance. That's the `self` in the method signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @TigerhawkT3 mentioned, you're calling the method as if it were a static method, rather than a class method.

> In Python, the first argument of every class method (including `init`)
>   is always a reference to the current instance of the class. By
>   convention, this argument is always named `self`.[¹](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

In order to call this method properly, you need to create an instance of class `SkypeBot` and *then* call `msg()`:

```
sbot = SkypeBot()
sbot.msg(message)
```

For more information on the language design decisions that went into the explicit declaration of `self` as a parameter, see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) and this article by [Guido van Rossum](https://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

Comment: when i try to make as you say i recive this

лют 10 11:24:08 PK odoo12[9310]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'msg'.
This code
sbot = skype_model.SkypeBot()
            sbot.msg(message)

Comment: It seems that constructing and initializing the instance `sbot` is failing. Are you sure that you've accounted for all the dependencies of the class `SkypeBot`?

Comment: It seems I have a problem with the initialization of the odoo environment but I can understand exactly where